# Alguien sabe como solucionar esto de "Requiere una asignación del origen del paquete" / Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, .net, nuget, newtonsoft

acudo a esta gran comunidad debido a que estoy iniciando en un trabajo remoto, con el que no tengo mucha ayuda.
En fin debo hacer un proyecto en .NET SQL SERVER Y REACT, no estoy tan familiarizado, pero se hace lo que se puede.
El objetivo del proyecto es desarrollar un programa el cual Extraiga datos de una plataforma (Siigo) y los muestre en el cliente de React, esto para poder editar, eliminar, y ver un poco de información de algunos datos.
¡Les agradezco si tienen algún tutorial similar o información que me pueda acortar tiempo, Muchas gracias!

Al intentar instalar paquetes de NuGet específicamente (Newtonsoft.Json) me sale este problema "Requiere una asignación del origen del paquete"

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: Nunca me ha aparecido ese error, pero si estas usando una de las últimas versiones de .net no necesitas newtosoft, .net trae consigo un buen parseador `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`. Además para un API en .net no necesitas usar directamente ninguno parseador, .net lo hace solo

Comment: ¿Puedes dar más detalles sobre las versiones que estás usando? ¿En qué versión de .NET estás? ¿Estás en Visual Studio? Si es así ¿qué versión? De todos modos, como dijo @Yussef, probablemente puedas hacer lo que quieres hacer con `System.Text.Json`

Answer (score 0):

Pude dar solución a este pequeño problema deshabilitando el origen del paquete, realmente estaba estancado por algo que no era tan problema, Muchas gracias a todos!